How to pass an event to html tag under canvas?
I'm trying to make a whiteboard in body tag with canvas
but can't pass event to input tag under canvas.
Is it possible to pass a mouse click event to the input tag under canvas tag without change order of tag or z-index?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      div {
        position: relative;
      }
      canvas {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
      }

      input {
        /* position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 60px; */
        color: #000;
        border: 1px solid #000;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      window.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
          context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
          MARGIN = 35,
          RADIUS = canvas.width / 2 - MARGIN;
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(
          canvas.width / 2,
          canvas.height / 2,
          RADIUS,
          0,
          Math.PI * 2,
          true
        );
        context.stroke();
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="input tag" />
      <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">
        Canvas not supported
      </canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>




Why not put the input on top of the canvas?

I'm trying to create a whiteboard so we can draw text or pictures on html tags.

You can set the CSS pointer-events property on the canvas to none.
Original example:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      div {
        position: relative;
      }
      canvas {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
        pointer-events: none;
      }

      input {
        /* position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 60px; */
        color: #000;
        border: 1px solid #000;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      window.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
          context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
          MARGIN = 35,
          RADIUS = canvas.width / 2 - MARGIN;
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(
          canvas.width / 2,
          canvas.height / 2,
          RADIUS,
          0,
          Math.PI * 2,
          true
        );
        context.stroke();
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="input tag" />
      <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">
        Canvas not supported
      </canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



Updated example
The events that are related to the canvas (click, mousedown, mousemove ect.) are not related to or specific for the canvas element. If you can track the mouse or a pointer device over the same area, that is fine. So, here I have the event listeners on the parent <div> for the canvas. The <div> contains the canvas and has the same coordinate point in the upper left corner. So, the canvas can still have the property pointer-events set to none, and you can use the <div> for tracking the position of the mouse/pointer device.
I changed the CSS position properties to a grid layout, where the input element and the canvas are placed in the same grid area, and therefore still overlapping. A kind of modern version of the position property...


const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
  context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  container = document.getElementById("container");
var MARGIN = 35,
  RADIUS = canvas.width / 2 - MARGIN;
container.mousedown = false;
context.beginPath();
context.arc(
  canvas.width / 2,
  canvas.height / 2,
  RADIUS,
  0,
  Math.PI * 2,
  true
);
context.stroke();

container.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  let container = e.target.closest('#container');
  container.mousedown = true;
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
  container.mousedown = false;
});

container.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  let container = e.target.closest('#container');
  let canvasX = e.clientX - container.offsetLeft;
  let canvasY = e.clientY - container.offsetTop;
  if (container.mousedown) draw(canvasX, canvasY);
});

function draw(x, y) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.fill();
}
body {
  margin: 10px 0 0 50px;
}

div#container {
  display: grid;
}

canvas {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  pointer-events: none;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

input {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  place-self: start;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="input tag" />
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">
        Canvas not supported
  </canvas>
</div>




Since I need to be able to draw with the pencil function on the Canvas tag, can both the Canvas and input tag receive events?

@S.J.Lim not at the same time, no. You'll either need to implement some sort of toggle to let the user put the whole thing into "drawing mode" or "element selection mode"; or you will have to capture the coordinates of the click on the canvas, and then write your own logic to determine if it would hit any of the input fields at that position, so that you can then focus the relevant one.

@S.J.Lim I updated my answer. Just because there are no events on the canvas doesn't mean that you cannot track mouse movements.
